# Why is this inner div centered inside the containing div but the button is not?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E1B1B;
  border-color: grey;
}

.nav-col {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 700px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="nav-col">
  <div style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
  <button style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the div, nor the button is centered.

The **contents** of the div and button are centred within the div and the button.

The div is the width of the container it is inside (you can see this by setting a background colour on it).  The button is the minimum width it needs to be.

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E1B1B;
  border-color: grey;
}

.nav-col {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 700px;
  width: 150px;
}

.nav-col > div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-col">
  <div style="text-align:center">contents</div>
  <button style="text-align:center;">contents</button>
</div>
```

`text-align` affects the position of the *inline content of the element*, not the element itself.

If you want to centre the button, then you need to set `text-align` on the button's container.

```css
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1E1B1B;
  border-color: grey;
}

.nav-col {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 700px;
  width: 150px;
}

.nav-col > div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-col">
  <div style="text-align:center">contents</div>
  <button style="text-align:center;">contents</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have made an edit to my question. I meant centered within the containing `div`

Comment: @ganidat — As this answer says: It isn't. It is the width of the containing div, it isn't centred.

Answer (score 0):

The `div` has a width of 100% by default and the `button` has a width similar to `width: fit-content` (it's only as big as it's contents).

In order to center the button, you can try

```
button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also, I would avoid mixing inline styles with separated styles, and I would put your CSS in a CSS sheet separately.